# Convexify $x\le a+by^2$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints, convex-geometry

I have the following non-convex constraint:
$$
x\le a+by^2\quad\text{where}\quad a,b>0,\,y\in[0,y_{max}]\text{ and }a\approx by_{max}^2
$$
On a drawing, it looks something like this:
[image]

The above figure also shows a possible convexification, but one that I don't like because for small $y$ it allows some infeasible $x$ values and for large $y$ it forbids having some feasible $x$ values.

My question: can I do *better*? Thanks for helping!

Comment: It is difficult to answer without knowing what you are trying to do. Since the feasible region is not convex, **any** convex approximation must be either infeasible or too strict at some point.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I'm just looking for a way of convexifying this constraint, for example by introducing slack variables or relaxations. If it helps, I know that the optimal solution of the associated optimization problem is likely to lie closer to smaller $y$ values than larger ones.

Comment: There is no way of guessing at 'better' unless you say what you want. In some cases a relaxed version of the constraint might be sufficient for your purposes (that is, take the convex hull of the feasible region). In other cases, you could look for a solution to a stricter problem (take the lines tangent to the curve at any point in $[0,y_\max]$) and then optimize the resulting optimum over all such tangents (sort of like solving the dual in some vague way). Assuming a solution exists, and assuming you can solve the stricter convex problems, this will find a solution.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the constraint. What variables are design parameters? $x, y_\max$?

Comment: @space_voyager, I think the common conceptual issue you are facing in the last couple of your questions is that you seem to think that there ought to be some sort of "one-shot" method for converting a non-convex problem into a convex one. There simply isn't. You may in fact have better luck with standard non-convex optimization methods such as SQP, trust-region methods, etc. In many cases, these techniques employ convexification strategies *on each iteration.*

Comment: @MichaelGrant You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I'll be trying sequential convex optimization to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A convex relaxation of the constraint would give you the convex hull of the feasible region:  in this case $$z \le a + b  y y_{max}$$